# PlanGrid API - Publish Log still prompts for version set name after UploadVersion

Tags: c#

I'm trying to post a file to my PlanGrid project using the following code.  Once the upload is complete, I log into the website, open the Publish Log, then click on "Publish Your Sheets", at which point it asks me again to define version set.  Can someone clarify what the UploadVersionRequest.VersionName property is used for then?

```
 public static async Task Upload(string project_uid, string filename, Stream payload)
 {
     var api = PlanGridClient.Create(Properties.Settings.Default.ApiKey);

     var versionRequest = new UploadVersionRequest
     {
         NumberOfFiles = 1,
         VersionName = "MyVersion"  // how does this get used??
     };

     var versionUpload = await api.UploadVersion(project_uid, versionRequest);

     foreach (var fileUploadRequest in versionUpload.FileUploadRequests)
     {
         var uploadFile = new UploadFile
         {
             FileName = filename
         };

         var fileUpload = await api.UploadFileToVersion(project_uid, versionUpload.Uid, fileUploadRequest.Uid, uploadFile);

         await api.Upload<object>(fileUpload, payload);
     }

     await api.CompleteVersionUpload(project_uid, versionUpload.Uid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. We released an update to the upload process that included both version name and issue date. That change has not been reflected in the API, so when you set the version name in the API, it is not reflected during the publishing process.